# Visualizing the variable DAG in a stan / brms model

Tags: data-visualization, stan

I would like to visualize the relationships between variables in the brms / stan models I write. I could make these myself for each model, but I'm hoping there's a package to generate them automatically. Does this exist?

Here are examples from pymc3 and greta:

pymc3: For some `model` you can call `pm.model_to_graphviz(model)` and get a result like this:

[image: pymc3 parameter dag]

greta: Pulling from the [8 schools example](https://greta-stats.org/articles/analyses/eight_schools.html), `plot(model)` produces a graph like this:
[image: greta parameter dag for 8 schools model]

In case the pictures above are unclear or fail to appear, let me describe in a little more detail. I'd like to visualize the model itself, seeing a DAG of how the parameters relate to one another (before doing any sampling). This is different than bayesplot or other tools that plot priors, posteriors, or MCMC draws.

Comment: There is no tag for model visualization, so `data-visualization` will have to do.

Comment: Nothing like that exists yet. https://github.com/stan-dev/bayesplot/issues/194

Answer (score 0):

As of May 2020, this doesn't exist. Thanks [Ben Goodrich](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/16579/ben-goodrich) for letting me know and pointing to the relevant Github issue!
https://github.com/stan-dev/bayesplot/issues/194